# LINQ : Take after GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

Assume that we have list of results

> OriginId , DestinationName , TotalTime
>           1 , 2 , 700
>           1 , 3 , 200 
>           1 , 4  , 300 
>           1,   5  , 400
>           2 , 2 , 100
>           2 , 3 , 900 
>           2 , 4  , 300 
>           2,   5  , 400
>           3 , 2 , 100
>           3 , 3 , 500 
>           3 , 4  , 300 
>           3,   5  , 400

```
public class Result 
  {
    public int OriginId {get;set;}
    public int DestinationId {get;set;}
    public int TotalTime {get;set;}
  }
```

I want to group list of results by OriginId and then sort them by TotalTime then take 2 destinationId or result.
The result should be something like this :

> OriginId , DestinationName , TotalTime 
>   1,3,200
>   1,4,300
>  
>   2,2,100
>   2,4,300
>   3,2,100
>   3,4,300

After grouping data by OriginId I don't have access TotalTime to order or DestinationId to take.

How do I do this ?

Comment: If you group them by OriginId you can't sort by `TotalTime` because in each group you have multiple `TotalTimes`, so do you have `DestinationNames`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.OriginId)
    .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.TotalTime).Take(2))
```

This should give you the expected output.Here is the result in `LinqPad`

[image]

Comment: Very good answer. +1 for this particular use of `SelectMany`.